# Modify prices on a page with Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I would like to modify prices on a page with Tampermonkey.

```
<span class="productNormalPrice">€1,00 inc. Tax</span>
<span class="productNormalPrice">€2,00 inc. Tax</span>
<span class="productNormalPrice">€3,00 inc. Tax</span>
```

...so I have multiple price spans on a page. I would like to modify these prices (multiply by 1.30).

So far I can parse these numbers as float:

```
parseFloat($(".productNormalPrice").text().replace(',','.').replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''), 10)
```

Can you help me with the next step?

Comment: Why are you using TamperMonkey to modify prices?

Comment: Fill in the missing code `$(".productNormalPrice").each((i, el) => $(el).text('€' + 1.3 * parseFloat($(el).text().replace......)))`